# how to know if gecko browser completed loading a webpage?

Tags: c#, .net, gecko, geckofx

As the title says, how can i know if the gecko browser completed loading a web page?
I know there is document_completed event. But it will get triggered for every time a web page loads. 
Are there any other ways to check if the current webpage is completed loading.

Answer (score 3):

My Solotion in vb.net and GeckoFX v45.0.34.0 you can use this tool convert to c# (http://converter.telerik.com/):

```
Private vWeb As GeckoWebBrowser = New GeckoWebBrowser
Private Property pageready As Boolean = False

Private Sub WaitForPageLoad()
    AddHandler vWeb.DocumentCompleted, New EventHandler(Of GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs)(AddressOf PageWaiter)

    While Not pageready
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While

    pageready = False
End Sub

Private Sub PageWaiter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    If vWeb.IsBusy = False Then
        pageready = True
        RemoveHandler vWeb.DocumentCompleted, New EventHandler(Of GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs)(AddressOf PageWaiter)
    End If
End Sub
```

Using:

```
vWeb.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
WaitForPageLoad()
//Do your Work
```

Hope this solution to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do While WebBrowser.IsBusy = True
Application.DoEvents()
Loop
```

Works for me. After `WebBrowser.Navigate` you have to wait for some time (I use 1 second) before `IsBusy` becomes `True`