# How to check in Linux that a browser has completed downloading a webpage?

Tags: url, browser, download

In automating processes sometimes webpages get involved. And sometimes it's not possible to access the HTML code in a direct way (e.g. javascript needed) so you need a browser to fetch the content of the URL. Now, in order to process that content you need to be sure that the download is complete. How can you do that? Is there any Linux command that can check that?

Note: The question is general, for any browser, not for particular cases (like [Gecko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116446/how-to-know-if-gecko-browser-completed-loading-a-webpage)).

Comment: Any browser, but also asking for a Linux command. I'm confused, what do you need?

Comment: @GolezTrol question edited for Linux system only.